# How can I make a recursive search for longest node more efficient?

Tags: python, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to find the longest path in a Directed Acyclic graph. At the moment, my code seems to be running time complexity of **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**.

The graph is of input `{0: [1,2], 1: [2,3], 3: [4,5] }`

```
#Input: dictionary: graph, int: start, list: path
#Output: List: the longest path in the graph (Recurrance)
# This is a modification of a depth first search
def find_longest_path(graph, start, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    paths = path
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_longest_path(graph, node, path)
            #Only take the new path if its length is greater than the current path
            if(len(newpaths) > len(paths)):
                paths = newpaths

    return paths
```

It returns a list of nodes in the form e.g. `[0,1,3,5]`

How can I make this more efficient than **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**? Is recursion the right way to solve this or should I be using a different loop?

Comment: Could you run this through a profiler to see what the pain points for performance are?

Comment: Side note: [Using an empty list as a default argument doesn't do what many new Python programmers would initially expect](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Comment: First, fix the default argument as chucksmash suggested.  Second, add code to track the longest known path to each visited node, rather than just the present path.  Your current algorithm finds every path in the graph, even when the current path is (could be) known to be inferior.

Comment: The default argument isn't a problem in this code because the list is not being modified in place (rather, it's used to build another new list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem in **O(n+e)** (i.e. linear in the number of nodes + edges).

The idea is that you first create a topological sort (I'm a fan of [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Tarjan.27s_algorithm)) and the set of reverse edges.  It always helps if you can decompose your problem to leverage existing solutions.

You then walk the topological sort backwards pushing to each parent node its child's distance + 1 (keeping maximums in case there are multiple paths).  Keep track of the node with the largest distance seen so far.

When you have finished annotating all of the nodes with distances you can just start at the node with the largest distance which will be your longest path root, and then walk down your graph choosing the children that are exactly one count less than the current node (since they lie on the critical path).

In general, when trying to find an optimal complexity algorithm don't be afraid to run multiple stages one after the other.  Five **O(n)** algorithms run sequentially is still **O(n)** and is still better than **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** from a complexity perspective (although it may be worse real running time depending on the constant costs/factors and the size of **n**).

**ETA:** I just noticed you have a start node.  This makes it simply a case of doing a depth first search and keeping the longest solution seen so far which is just **O(n+e)** anyway.  Recursion is fine or you can keep a list/stack of visited nodes (you have to be careful when finding the next child each time you backtrack).

As you backtrack from your depth first search you need to store the longest path from that node to a leaf so that you don't re-process any sub-trees.  This will also serve as a `visited` flag (i.e. in addition to doing the `node not in path` test also have a `node not in subpath_cache` test before recursing).  Instead of storing the subpath you could store the length and then rebuild the path once you're finished based on sequential values as discussed above (critical path).

**ETA2:** Here's a solution.

```
def find_longest_path_rec(graph, parent, cache):
    maxlen = 0
    for node in graph[parent]:
        if node in cache:
            pass
        elif node not in graph:
            cache[node] = 1
        else:
            cache[node] = find_longest_path_rec(graph, node, cache)

        maxlen = max(maxlen, cache[node])

    return maxlen + 1

def find_longest_path(graph, start):
    cache = {}
    maxlen = find_longest_path_rec(graph, start, cache)
    path = [start]
    for i in range(maxlen-1, 0, -1):
        for node in graph[path[-1]]:
            if cache[node] == i:
                path.append(node)
                break
        else:
            assert(0)
    return path
```

Note that I've removed the `node not in path` test because I'm assuming that you're actually supplying a DAG as claimed.  If you want that check you should really be raising an error rather than ignoring it.  Also note that I've added the assertion to the `else` clause of the `for` to document that we must always find a valid next (sequential) node in the path.

**ETA3:**   The final `for` loop is a little confusing.  What we're doing is considering that in the critical path all of the node distances must be sequential.  Consider node 0 is distance 4, node 1 is distance 3 and node 2 is distance 1.  If our path started `[0, 2, ...]` we have a contradiction because node 0 is not 1 further from a leaf than 2.

Comment: thanks for this - I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with this. So just confirming that I should run a full DFS and find the longest length from the start node, and then iterate through the rest to confirm they're all smaller? This is definetely much, much faster than my implementation, but why would I need to backtrack in that way

Comment: @AucklandInvader No, you're not finding the longest then checking the others are shorter.  You're doing a DFS to generate annotations in the graph which then make extracting the longest path trivial.  I've always found graph algorithms easiest to do this way, first an annotation sweep, then a result extraction.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of non-algorithmic improvements I'd suggest (these are related to Python code quality):

```
def find_longest_path_from(graph, start, path=None):
    """
    Returns the longest path in the graph from a given start node
    """
    if path is None:
        path = []
    path = path + [start]
    max_path = path
    nodes = graph.get(start, [])
    for node in nodes:
        if node not in path:
            candidate_path = find_longest_path_from(graph, node, path)
            if len(candidate_path) > len(max_path):
                max_path = candidate_path
    return max_path

def find_longest_path(graph):
    """
    Returns the longest path in a graph
    """
    max_path = []
    for node in graph:
        candidate_path = find_longest_path_from(graph, node)
        if len(candidate_path) > len(max_path):
            max_path = candidate_path
    return max_path
```

**Changes explained:**

```
def find_longest_path_from(graph, start, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []
```

1. I've renamed `find_longest_path` as `find_longest_path_from` to better explain what it does.
2. Changed the `path` argument to have a default argument value of `None` instead of `[]`. Unless you know you will specifically benefit from them, you want to avoid using mutable objects as default arguments in Python. This means you should typically set `path` to `None` by default and then when the function is invoked, check whether `path is None` and create an empty list accordingly.

---

```
max_path = path
...
candidate_path = find_longest_path_from(graph, node, path)
...
```

I've updated the names of your variables from `paths` to `max_path` and `newpaths` to `candidate_path`. These were confusing variable names because they referred to the plural of path -- implying that the value they stored consisted of multiple paths -- when in fact they each just held a single path. I tried to give them more descriptive names.

---

```
nodes = graph.get(start, [])
for node in nodes:
```

Your code errors out on your example input because the leaf nodes of the graph are not keys in the `dict` so `graph[start]` would raise a `KeyError` when `start` is `2`, for instance. This handles the case where `start` is not a key in `graph` by returning an empty list.

---

```
def find_longest_path(graph):
    """
    Returns the longest path in a graph
    """
    max_path = []
    for node in graph:
        candidate_path = find_longest_path_from(graph, node)
        if len(candidate_path) > len(max_path):
            max_path = candidate_path
    return max_path
```

A method to find the longest path in a graph that iterates over the keys. This is entirely separate from your algorithmic analysis of `find_longest_path_from` but I wanted to include it.